# send data through URI datastore

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, restful-architecture

I'm using restful to send my data with HTTP GET POST etc. I want to use the data store on Google App Engine. Can someone explain where is URI located for the data store on  Google App Engine so I can send data to it?

Comment: App Engine's datastore, per se, offers no REST architecture.  You can easily put one on top of it, of course, with a simple Google App Engine application -- perhaps simplest via Google Cloud Endpoints.  Or, you could use Google Cloud Storage, which is a very different product from the App Engine's datastore.

Comment: What do you mean I can put a rest on top of it. I have created an application already but I cant find the datastore's uri.

Comment: I mean you write a Google App Engine application -- the only way to access the GAE datastore! -- which connects to the datastore via its API (e.g, if your app is Python, the `ndb` package) and exposes the datastore entities to the outside world via a REST API.  With Google Cloud Endpoints (at least in Python, with the open source endpoints-datastore bridge package) you can automate that (and automatically get handy libraries generated for even easier use from IOS and Android, if you wish).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're developing in Java you should take a look at the most popular library which is [Objectify](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/)

> Objectify is a Java data access API specifically designed for the
>   Google App Engine datastore. It occupies a "middle ground"; easier to
>   use and more transparent than JDO or JPA, but significantly more
>   convenient than the Low-Level API. Objectify is designed to make
>   novices immediately productive yet also expose the full power of the
>   GAE datastore. Objectify lets you persist, retrieve, delete, and query
>   your own typed objects.

Sample entity:

```
@Entity
class Car {
    @Id String vin; // Can be Long, long, or String
    String color;
}
```

How to create and save entity to datastore:

```
ofy().save().entity(new Car("123123", "red")).now();
```